# How to access GIS.se site stats?

Tags: support, status-completed, statistics

I was recently at [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) and noticed a nifty site stats section.  Is there a way to access these site stats for GIS.se?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These stats are posted when a site is in its beta stage.  The final stats for our site are available at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems:

[image]

You can query information about site usage at the [data site](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/queries).  For instance, [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/6134/total-questions-and-answers-per-month-for-the-last-12) reports total questions and answers by month for the last 12 months.  You can customize these queries.

Comment: There is also the Data Explorer API that covers all SE sites  http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: +1 for the data site.  There is pretty amazing functionality there.

Comment: Just be aware, Aaron, that it is based on slightly out-of-date data (usually they are about a month old).  Although your site moderators have access to current data, we are enjoined from sharing it directly. At best we can provide verbal summaries.